# jquery TableSorter - How do I turn off filters dynamically

Tags: jquery, filter, tablesorter

I am using TableSorter Version 2.28.1.  I have filters turned on.

```
 widgets: ["zebra", "filter"]
```

I want to be able to turn the filters off or on in my code before displaying the table.  This based upon parameters coming in from the previous page.

I am using C# and the table on the page is a .net Gridview control.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a combination of the [applyWidgetId](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#applywidgetid) and [removeWidget](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#removewidget) methods to toggle the filter widget ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bbxxomhx/622/)):

HTML

```
<button type="button">Add Filter</button>
<table class="tablesorter">...</table>
```

Script

```
$(function() {
    var $table = $('table');

    $('button').click(function(){
    var btn = $(this),
        addWidget = /add/i.test(btn.text());
    if (addWidget) {
      btn.text('Remove Filter');
      $table.trigger('applyWidgetId', 'filter');
    } else {
      btn.text('Add Filter');
      $table.trigger('removeWidget', 'filter');
    }
    return false;
  });

  $table.tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    widgets: ['zebra']
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Mottie.  The "applyWidgetId" was what I needed.    For me it was a little simpler.  I just needed to be able to either have the filter on or off at initialization time based upon a value of a variable .    So this is what I did ...

```
widgets: ["zebra"],
initialized: function (table) {                
    if ('<%= showFilter %>' == 'Y')
    {
        $(table).trigger('applyWidgetId', 'filter')
    }
```

Comment: It might be even easier to add it to the `widgets`... `widgets: ["zebra", ("<%= showFilter %>" === "Y" ? "filter": "")]`

Comment: Thanks @Mottie That is easier.